# What is Kubernetes max available cpu/mem resourceQuota for a namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

Is Kubernetes max available cpu/mem resourceQuota for a namespace the total of #cpu across all nodes in the cluster or per node? i.e if I have 4 nodes each with **cpu=10 and mem=100Gi**, to set 50% resources to the namespace, would that be limits.cpu: "20" (4*10/2) or "5" (10 per node/2). I'm using statefulsets w/label+namespace for node selection so that pods are specifically deployed to use only these 4 nodes. I think it would have to be the latter, so:
    **limits.cpu: "5"
    limits.memory: 50Gi**
would allow each node in that namespace to use **50% of the resources**. One reason I ask is it may not always be true that each node has the same number cpu/memory, i.e. 50% resources on one node may not be 50% on another node - in my cluster they are the same, but I can see where that might not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the sum of CPU of all worker nodes

[image]

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#compute-resource-quota

If Pods in Running state exceeds that amount k8s fails to schedule the Pods because there aren't nodes available to fulfill the request

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed that in docs, but examples I saw didn't seem to reflect what's in the docs.